# sum a number inside a map function and return the edited array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I want to find a property by ID, and if I find it I want to add + to the quantity property.

This is what I have tried but cant achieve to return the previous object with the new edited quantity.

any thoughts?

```js
const object = [
  {
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b75',
  quantity: 1,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
},
{
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b76',
  quantity: 1,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
},
{
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77',
  quantity: 1,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
}
]

function findID(arr, val ){
  return arr.map(function(arrVal){
    if( val === arrVal.productId){
      return [...arr, {arrVal.quantity +1 }]
    }
  })
}

findID(object, '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77')
```

In this case Id like to return:

```
const object = [
  {
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b75',
  quantity: 1,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
},
{
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b76',
  quantity: 1,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
},
{
  _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
  productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77',
  quantity: 2,
  createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should give you exactly what you're looking for. The function finds the object, adds `1` to the quantity, and then returns the updated array of objects per your specifications.

```js
const object = [{
    _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
    productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b75',
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
    productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b76',
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
  },
  {
    _id: '6078db5aa82f5c34409d53f4',
    productId: '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77',
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-04-16T00:33:46.816Z'
  }
];

const findID = (arr, id) => (arr.find(product => product.productId === id && ++product.quantity), arr);

console.log(findID(object, '60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77'));
```

Another possible case to consider here would be to return something else like `false` if the object is not found rather than just returning the array of objects as is. You could even add a third parameter to support that option conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

```
(object.find((v)=>v.productId==='60709d8f24a9615d9cff2b77') || {}).quantity++;
```

You can use this code